# QtProcess get output data

Tags: qt

I am unable to get the output data of the application during it is running. I start the application with the `QtProcess`. My code is simple and straight forward. A `QPushButton` does create a new thread which calls the `solverThread` function given below. I get the output of the application, if I stop it or if it is finished but I want to get it during the run. It is a linear solver that is running and I want to log it into a file. I wanted to pipe the output direct into a file but did not have access.

```
void Analyzer::solverThread() const
{
    qDebug() << "Start executing the application";

    QProcess solver;

    // Path to executable
    const QString binPath = ui_->pathBin->text();

    // Start application
    solver.start(binPath + "/myApplication");

    // Stop if either the user push the button or the application finishes
    while (solverThreadActive_)
    {
        // Here I want to get the already done output
        // The application procudes a lot of data 
        // (linear solver information which I want to log into a file directly)


        if (solver.waitToFinished(1000)) break;
    }

    // User quit
    if (!solverThreadActive) solver.kill();

    // Get output - works but I need the intermediate state, e.g. if there is a new output I want it. The lines below just give me everything at the end.
    QByteArray tmp = solver.readAll();
    qDebug() << tmp;
    solver.close();

    qDebug() << "Simulation done...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem is very simple: The keyword is `setStandardOutputFile()` from the `QtProcess` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setStandardOutputFile)